# Data is printing multiple time in php?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

The course name php is available in the table one time but when I retrieve it from table it printing multiple time. I have tried the following code - please help me what's wrong with the code? (if I remove the drop down which is available below the heading it is printing single time in the table)

```
<?php
include("session.php");
?>
<?php
include("../view/common/head.php");
?>
<?php
  include('../view/common/tab.php');
  ?>
<body class="bg-color">

<div class="container">
<h1> List Of Courses</h1>
<br/>
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['message1']))
{
 echo $_SESSION['message1'];
 unset($_SESSION['message1']);
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['courseupdated']))
{
 echo $_SESSION['courseupdated'];
 unset($_SESSION['courseupdated']);
}
?>
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['deletecourse']))
{
 echo $_SESSION['deletecourse'];
 unset($_SESSION['deletecourse']);
}
?>
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['notdelete']))
{
 echo $_SESSION['notdelete'];
 unset($_SESSION['notdelete']);
}
?> <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
   <select class="form-control">
<?php
include('../model/functions.php');
$table="courses";
$condition="";
$drop=Selectdata($table,$condition);
foreach($selectarray as $drop)
{
  echo '<option value="'.$drop['course_id'].'">'.$drop['course_name'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>       
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sno</th>
 <th>Course Name</th>
 <th>Course Description</th>
 <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <?php
  $per_page=5;

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {

$page = $_GET['page'];

}

else {

$page=1;

}


$table="courses";
$per_page=5;
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
$condition="limit ".$start_from.",".$per_page." ";
$limit=Selectdata($table,$condition);
if($rowcount==0)
{
  echo "no records found";
}
else
{
$sno=($page-1) * $per_page;
 foreach($selectarray as $course){
    $sno++;
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>'.$sno.'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$course['course_name'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$course['course_description'].'</td>';
   echo '<td><a href="editcourse.php?id='.$course['course_id'].'"><button type="submit">edit</button></a><a href="../controller/deletecourse.php?id='.$course['course_id'].'"><button Onclick="return ConfirmDelete();"  type="submit">Delete</button></a></td>';
   echo '</tr>';
 }
 }
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<a href="adminmanagecourse.php">Click here to add new course</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
</div>

<?php

$table = "courses";
$condition=" ";
$select=Selectdata($table,$condition);
$total_records = $rowcount;
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

echo '<div class="text-center">';
echo '<ul class="pagination">';
echo "<li><a href='courselist.php?page=1'>".'<<'.'</a></li>';
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
echo "<li><a href='courselist.php?page=".$i."'>".$i.'</a></li>';
}
echo "<li><a href='courselist.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>>'.'</a></li>';
echo "</ul>";
echo '</div>';

?>

<?php
include("../view/common/footer.php");
?>
```

functions.php

```
function Selectdata($table,$condition="")
{
    global $conn,$result,$selectarray,$rowcount;

    $sql="SELECT * from ".$table." ".$condition." ";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    $rowcount=$result->num_rows;
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {   
        $selectarray[]=$row;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Please post ur query!

Comment: if i remove the drop down which is avaliable below the heading the data is printing single time.this problem occured after i put the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code is not intended to be used in a real project.

Just add

```
$selectarray = array();
```

before

```
while
```

in `Selectdata` function definition.

What happens is that each time you call that function it just amends the full rowset to the same array as it is global.

Comment: Thank you now its fine im just learning im not going to use this code in real project

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach($selectarray as $row)
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['course_id'].'">'.$row['course_name'].'</option>';
}
```